# Translate Pages by store view

Tags: magento2, store-view, localisation, page

In Magento admin, I tried to create new page for different language (in **CONTENT > PAGES**). However, when I enter the same URL Key (i.e. home) and save, it prompt out error.

> URL key for specified store already exists.

I expected all three pages in different store views should belong to the same URL, anyone got any idea?

Comment: Yes its expected behaviour because you have already `home` as url key, so for solution i can say for different  store view use different url , you can give same name but url key will be unique. so pass like home then for french storeview url key like `home-fr` etc . so it will resolve the error. Hope it make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can achieve this by creating the different CMS pages which assign to the different Store Views.

For example: we have three store views, we can create three different CMS pages with the same url key (for example, `my-contact-page`). **Remember that each page must be assigned to the different Store View**.

[image]

Especially for Home page, we can set the CMS home page for each store view in **STORES> Configuration > General Web > Default Pages**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. Finally I am done with the same URL key in different store view. I have to delete my old page first. But I guess it's Magento2 bug. I have created a page, and set to All store view , then I edit it to English Store View, and I am not able to add Traidtional Chinese store view with same URL key.